Malformed root json at /home/runner/work/Remember-Me/Remember-Me/app/google-services.json
I ignored google-services.json from my repo, but I'm using Github Actions to build the APK, so I need that google-services.json file eventually, I followed an article that suggests to encode the file and saved in GitHub Secrets and decoded during the build in android.yml file. But I get the error that there is some Malformed root json! 
Her is the steps I followed:

Decode the google-services.json
$ base64 google-services.json 

Save the results in GitHub Secrets
I created a new key under the name GOOGLE_SERVICES_JSON
Create a step in the android.yml to decode and decrypt the file
name: Android CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: set up JDK 17
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: '17'
          distribution: 'zulu'
          cache: gradle

      - name: Cache Gradle packages
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: |
            ~/.gradle/caches
            ~/.gradle/wrapper
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-gradle-${{ hashFiles('**/*.gradle*', '**/gradle-wrapper.properties') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-gradle-

      - name: Load Google Service file
        env:
          data: ${{secrets.GOOGLE_SERVICES_JSON}}
        run: echo $DATA | base64 -di > app/google-services.json

      - name: Grant execute permission for gradlew
        run: chmod +x gradlew
      - name: Build with Gradle
        run: ./gradlew build

      - name: Upload build artifacts
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: build
          path: app/build/outputs/apk/release/*.apk

The build failed with the following message:
Run ./gradlew build

Welcome to Gradle 8.6!

Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Configurable encryption key for configuration cache
 - Build init improvements
 - Build authoring improvements

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/8.6/release-notes.html

Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform-Tools in /usr/local/lib/android/sdk/licenses
License for package Android SDK Platform-Tools accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform-Tools v.35.0.1".
"Install Android SDK Platform-Tools v.35.0.1" ready.
Installing Android SDK Platform-Tools in /usr/local/lib/android/sdk/platform-tools
"Install Android SDK Platform-Tools v.35.0.1" complete.
"Install Android SDK Platform-Tools v.35.0.1" finished.
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:checkKotlinGradlePluginConfigurationErrors SKIPPED
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues
> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices FAILED
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Malformed root json at /home/runner/work/Remember-Me/Remember-Me/app/google-services.json
3 actionable tasks: 3 executed

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 22s
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.



I've faced the same problem, though I don't even use base64, I just copied google-services.json content into GitHub Secrets

Make sure the name of your secret in github secrets matches the in your script. For example, you created a repository secret called "GOOGLE_SERVICES_JSON_BASE64", it must match in the script. Environment variable name should also match in the run command:
  - name: Create Google Services JSON File
    env:
      GOOGLE_SERVICES_JSON: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_SERVICES_JSON_BASE64 }} #check the secret name
    run: echo $GOOGLE_SERVICES_JSON | base64 -di > app/google-services.json # GOOGLE_SERVICES_JSON

I can see in your script you declared data env variable, but in run command you put $DATA. Change both to lowercase or uppercase and try again. YAML is case-sensitive.
